# Custom ViewPager Indicator - drawable

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I need to create a ViewPager indicator that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxyXZ.jpg

I know that it is against UI guidelines of Android, but it is a client requirement. I have tried ViewPagerIndicator - TitlePageIndicator by Jack Wharton, but I can not customize the indicator. As it is, I can only change the color and height of the indicator, but I can not use a custom drawable.

Is there another library that can help me create this kind of sliding tabs with custom background and custom indicator (both drawables)?